# Since private MS store no longer working, what is the best practice to set policy on MS store?

Tags: microsoft-intune

Since private MS Store no longer work in the policy

What is the best practice to set policy on MS Store.

Atm, our company is blocking access to MS store, however this cause a lot of issue with autopilot and not getting Company Portal. I know we can put Company Portal in Intune which we already did, but even so Company Portal is installed in the laptop, however we can't open it. Also all those common apps from windows like calculator, clock, photos, etc are in stage as they are in progress of download/install, again can't open them.

Everyone is talking about WinGet, but if most company ban access to MS store, how will they able to effectively using WinGet as package manager?

Is there any way to get similar thing to private store in MS store?